# dotnet: not found in Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline)

Tags: .net, jenkins-pipeline

I have a `.net 6.0` console application. I have installed Jenkins on Docker. I am setting up the Jenkins CI pipeline using the Declarative Pipeline. The stage in `Jenkinsfile` which is causing this issue looks like the below code:

```
stage('Clean'){
    steps{
        sh "dotnet clean ${env.WORKSPACE}/GameOfDice.sln --configuration Release"
    }
}
```

All the above steps in the `Jenkinsfile` are running smoothly except for the `dotnet` commands. I am getting the below error:

```
+ dotnet clean /var/jenkins_home/workspace/CI_Demo_Pipeline/GameOfDice.sln --configuration Release
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/CI_Demo_Pipeline@tmp/durable-6af65ef9/script.sh: 1: dotnet: not found
```

I have also added `.NET SDK Support` and `MSBuild` plugins in Jenkins as well. Also, in the Dashboard > Global Tool Configuration, I have added
[MSBuild config in Global Tool Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGHzn.png). I don't know, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: dotnet sdk is not installed or not part of the path on the agent running the job. Check if it's installed on the agent, if it's consider restarting the agent.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts I am running Jenkins on Docker. How can I add dotnet SDK in order for Jenkins to find it?